# Is there any hook available so that i can add some columns or buttons in the content section of drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

Here i want to add a my own custom column in the content section through my own custom module which should automatically appear on the content section when module is installed , so in order to do that i looked for hooks available but could not find one. So can anyone suggest me some way in order to achieve this.[Content Section with the requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9neH.jpg)

Here in the above image i want to add a custom column.

Answer (score 0):

This is admin view,
You can achieve this by following:

1. Go to "/admin/structure/views/view/content" and add column manually
2. by using hook_views_pre_render and target view with machine name as "content".

Comment: can you provide some link for the reference or a part of code.

Comment: I hope this will help you:
https://drupalium.com/articles/insert-replace-delete-rows-from-view-results